# jquery javascript set values as float before adding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My app has a textbox on a webpage whose value is looked up and then added or subtracted to another value.

It seems to subtract well, but when adding, it interprets the value in the textbox as text, and adds on the other float as a text as well:

[image: subtracted a few times, then added as text]

Here's the source code of the thing changing:

```
  $('#mymoney').val($('#mymoney').val() +  $prevevent.close);

//...or when subtracting:...//

  $('#mymoney').val($('#mymoney').val() -  $prevevent.close);
```

How to I tell the mymoney to be interpreted as a float instead of a string?

Comment: I tried parseFloat but that didn't help. 
`$('#mymoney').val(parseFloat($('#mymoney').val() +  $prevevent.close));`
but as you can see I tried it around the whole expression, I'll just try it around  the first bit like you suggested.

Comment: In this case doing it around both causes a problem, as the string is being concatenated before the parsing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `.val()` is reading the value as a string and concatinating. You can parse it into a integer with `parseInt()`:

```
$('#mymoney').val( parseInt($('#mymoney').val()) +  $prevevent.close);
```

For float values use `parseFloat()`:

```
$('#mymoney').val( parseFloat($('#mymoney').val()) +  $prevevent.close);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple by using `parseFloat`

`$('#mymoney').val(parseFloat($('#mymoney').val()) +  $prevevent.close);`

Because JS will interpretes the other hand to string if either operator hand is a string.
Or, you can use `Number()` to parse string to (int or float) number like:

`$('#mymoney').val(Number($('#mymoney').val()) +  $prevevent.close);`

But the `parseInt or parseFloat is prefer`, because it acts more normally than `Number`. For Example, Number will parse `null` and `""` to 0, and erase the `0` at the beginning of a number although it may represent an octal digit. Additionally, `parseInt` will return the correct part until it can't be parsed, like: `parseInt("15abc")` returns `15`.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct. However, here is another syntactical spice of magic that will do wonders for integer values.

Instead of using `parseInt` you can just prepend your expression with a `+` and it will parse the following value to integer.

`$('#mymoney').val( (+$('#mymoney').val()) +  $prevevent.close);`

Comment: The unary plus operator does in fact parse a floating point value, not an integer..